# Combine every three columns in R

Tags: r, concatenation, paste

I have a matrix like this:

```
df <- matrix(sample(c(0,1,1),9000,replace=T),nrow=3,ncol=3000)
df[1:3,1:9]

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] 
[1,]    1    0    1    1    1    0    1    1    0   
[2,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    0   
[3,]    0    0    1    1    0    1    0    1    1
```

I want to combine every three columns so that:

```
        [,1] [,2] [,3] 
[1,]    101  110  110   
[2,]    111  111  110   
[3,]    001  101  011
```

Any ideas??
Thank you in advance

Comment: Does your Dataset contains only charactor or string ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `seq` on a loop to extract every 3 columns, then `paste` the values by row with `do.call` on a `data.frame`

```
out <- sapply(seq(1, ncol(df), by = 3), function(i)  
       do.call(paste0, as.data.frame(df[, i:(i+2)])))
```

---

Or another option is to do the `paste` once and then split

```
v1 <- do.call(paste0, as.data.frame(df))
read.fwf(textConnection(v1), widths = rep(3, nchar(v1[1])/3), 
      colClasses = "character")
#  V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  V6  V7  V8  V9 V10
#1 100 010 111 111 011 011 101 111 111 011
#2 001 101 111 101 101 111 101 111 111 111
#3 110 011 110 001 011 101 111 101 101 111
```

#### data

```
df <- matrix(sample(c(0, 1, 1), 90, replace = TRUE), nrow = 3,ncol = 30)
```

Comment: Like your `read.fwf` approach. Upvote for it ;)

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have dataset of 3 rows and 30 columns.

```
df <- matrix(sample(c(0,1,1),9000,replace=T),nrow=3,ncol=30)
```

Total Number of columns after combination of each 3 columns. Store into variable 'TotalColumnsAfter'

```
TotalColumnsAfter <-  ncol(df)/nrow(df)
```

Using array function. Convert into array.

```
ConvertIntoArray <- array(as.matrix(df), c(nrow(df), TotalColumnsAfter, ncol(df)/TotalColumnsAfter))
```

using apply function merge rows & columns of array. 'paste' is used for combining.

```
CombineDataset <- apply(ConvertIntoArray, 1:2, paste, collapse = "")
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Please don't hesitate to question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R option using `substring` to subset strings, i.e.,

```
t(
  sapply(
    do.call(paste0, data.frame(df)),
    function(x) substring(x, seq(1, nchar(x), 3), seq(3, nchar(x), 3)),
    USE.NAMES = FALSE
  )
)
```

which gives

```
     [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]  [,7]  [,8]  [,9]  [,10]
[1,] "101" "101" "110" "011" "110" "011" "111" "111" "010" "010"
[2,] "011" "101" "100" "010" "111" "011" "110" "110" "011" "011"
[3,] "101" "101" "001" "101" "111" "111" "011" "110" "100" "001"
```

**Data**

```
set.seed(0)
df <- matrix(sample(c(0, 1, 1), 90, replace = TRUE), nrow = 3, ncol = 30)

> df
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14]
[1,]    1    0    1    1    0    1    1    1    0     0     1     1     1     1
[2,]    0    1    1    1    0    1    1    0    0     0     1     0     1     1
[3,]    1    0    1    1    0    1    0    0    1     1     0     1     1     1
     [,15] [,16] [,17] [,18] [,19] [,20] [,21] [,22] [,23] [,24] [,25] [,26]
[1,]     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     1
[2,]     1     0     1     1     1     1     0     1     1     0     0     1
[3,]     1     1     1     1     0     1     1     1     1     0     1     0
     [,27] [,28] [,29] [,30]
[1,]     0     0     1     0
[2,]     1     0     1     1
[3,]     0     0     0     1
```